# How to get 2 random rows per user_id from a mySQL table?

Tags: mysql

I have a table that has many products from different `user_id`'s. Like this:

```
product_id | user_id
01           20
02           20
03           20
04           20
05           32
06           32
07           53
08           53
09           53
10           84
11           84
etc.
```

I'm trying to get exactly 2 rows for each different user_id, sorted randomly.

The closest I got is with this query:

```
SELECT * FROM db_products ORDER BY user_id, RAND()
```

But that gives me every row sorted randomly, instead of 2 rows for each user_id sorted randomly.

I tried a `LIMIT 2` but that shows only 2 rows total. What's the easiest way to achieve this?

Thank you so much for any help :)

Comment: Is it okay for the two "random" products to be the same?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is probably to use variables:

```
select p.*
from (select p.*,
             (@rn := if(@u = user_id, @rn + 1,
                        if(@u := user_id, 1, 1)
                       )
             ) as rn
      from db_products p cross join
           (select @u := 0, @rn := 0) params
      order by user_id, rand()
     ) p
where rn <= 2;
```

There are other possibilities.  If your strings are unlikely to overflow and you want the products on a single row:

```
select user_id,
       substring_index(group_concat(product_id order by rand(), ',', 2)
from db_products
group by user_id;
```